# What are strategies for maximizing the high score in Super Tribes?

Tags: super-tribes

Someone introduced me to the iOS game [*Super Tribes*](http://www.midjiwan.com/supertribes.html) by Midjiwan. It is a Civilization like turn based strategy game, but with a a limited number of 30 turns and fewer technology and unit options.

I am playing the game in *crazy mode* with limited turns (30) against two AI opponents and regularly win, with a score around 35.000 every time. By "winning" I mean eliminating all opponents, developing the whole technology tree, discovering the whole map and building as much improvements as possible.

These results however are pretty bad compared with the highscores available (I don’t know if they can be manipulated): Today’s highscore starts at 42.000, this week’s highscore at 49.000 and the all-time highscores start at 63.000 (and goes well over 100.000).

Do I miss some game mechanics here, leading to higher scores than those I currently archive?

What are strategies for maximizing the highscore in Super Tribes?

Answer (score 1):

With a score of 35k you're a bit over me, but I'll share my tips that got me good scores. You'll probably know most of these already, but here we go.

Start with the desert tribe. The Rider is invaluable at the start. Prioritize your next tech (farming, fishing, hunting, or mining) based on what resource is abundant near you.

I don't know about you, but generally the best strategy seemed to be kill on sight. No mercy. Wipe out the other tribes while they're small. With your next few techs, depending on how the game goes, try aiming for Climbing so you can get those awesome Swordsmen.

In endgame, once you've wiped out the other tribes, you should have 10 to 15 turns left to hunt for points. Focus on hunting/fishing/mining resources. Maxing out the tech trees does net you some extra points, but try instead aiming to harvest everything you can, and continually deploying troops so that all of your cities are full.

It's a matter of luck and balance, you just have to play around and find a good path to take.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The question however was on scoring better than I do now, so it obviously needs more than strategies that make players score *less*.